# srl and sll in MIPS code (Transfer from c to MIPS)

Tags: mips

Why need to use sll in this problem? How do we use sll and srl
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckKxO.png)

I understand most of MIPS code here, but I do not understand why need to use sll here, I do not really understand sll and srl.

Question:
For the following C statement, what is the corresponding MIPS assembly code? Assume that the
variables i, and j are assigned to registers $s3, and $s4, respectively. Assume that the base address of
the arrays A and B are in registers $s6 and $s7, respectively.
B[8] = A[i − j];

```
sub $t0, $s3, $s4
sll $t0, $t0, 2
add $t1, $s6, $t0
lw $t2, 0($t1)
sw $t2, 32($s7)
```

Comment: Please use text for text, [not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can format code with triple backtick fences ```. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to appreciate the nature of byte addressable memory architecture.

Every 8 bit byte has a unique memory address.

A 32 bit integer occupies 4 bytes, and hence 4 byte addresses.

So, in an array, if `a[0]` is at 0x10010000, then `a[1]` is at 0x10010004.  Note that we refer to a multibyte item by its lowest address.

Indexing then requires what we call scaling, here multiplying by 4, since each word occupies 4 bytes.

The formula for address of `a[i` is `i*4+a`.  Note that we don't see this scaling in C language, as it is automatically done &8212; the compiler knows the data types, and so it knows element size, i.e. scale factor.